# Xcode how to display array inside array in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitextview

In `Xcode5` I have application of recipes. 
screen1 is list of recipes in a tableview. The recipe are objects in an `array` at `MVC` model. at Screen1 when clicking on a row you move to screen2 to see a specific recipe Details.  One of them is Ingredients which I try to display as array (inside array) in `UITextView` (divided by \n).

I run the app - screen1 is displayed, but when clicking a row the app crashes at: signal SIGABRT.

Can you please advise what is best way to display array of ingredients in the textview?
Thanks in advance.
This is code at DetailsVC.m  (screen2):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.detailName.text = self.presentedRecipe.title;
    self.detailImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.presentedRecipe.imageName];

    NSMutableString *ingredientText = [NSMutableString string];

    for (NSString* ingredient in myRecipeDM.ingredients) {
        [ingredientText appendFormat:@"%@\n", ingredient];
    }
    self.ingTV.text = (NSString*) self.presentedRecipe.ingredients;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSString *final=[[NSString alloc] init];
for (NSString* ingredient in myRecipeDM.ingredients) 
{
    if[ingredientText isEqualToString:""]
    {
      ingredientText=ingredient;
     }
    else
    {
      ingredientText=final;
      ingredientText=[final stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@\n", ingredient];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
NSString *ingredientstring = @"";
for (NSString* ingredient in myRecipeDM.ingredients) 
{
ingredientstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", ingredientstring, ingredient];
}
_ingTV.text = ingredientstring;
```